# error with tooltip in datepicker bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, tooltip

Just have a question about my tooltip in the datepicker.
The calendar numbers are moving to the right if I add the tooltip to the datepicker. 
I can not reproduce the error with jsfiddle but following is the code and a picture. If I have a look at the tooltip it produces style="left:135.208px"?

[image: days moving]

[image: added style]

html

```
<div id="datepicker99"></div>
```

javascript

```
var datesGreen = ['3/12/2015', '4/12/2015'];
var datesYellow = ['16/12/2015', '17/12/2015', '18/12/2015'];
var datesRed = ['24/12/2015', '25/12/2015'];

$("#datepicker99").datepicker({
format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
autoclose: true,
todayHighlight: true,
beforeShowDay: function(date){
var d = date;
var curr_date = d.getDate();
var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
var formattedDate = curr_date + "/" + curr_month + "/" + curr_year

if ($.inArray(formattedDate, datesGreen) != -1){
  return {
    tooltip: 'text',
    classes: 'highlight-green'
  };
}
if ($.inArray(formattedDate, datesYellow) != -1){
  return {
    classes: 'highlight-yellow'
  };
}
if ($.inArray(formattedDate, datesRed) != -1){
  return {
    classes: 'highlight-red'
  };
 }
 return;
}
});
 $('.highlight-green').tooltip({placement : 'top'});
```

css

```
.ui-widget{
font-size: 0.7em;
}
td.highlight {
}
td.highlight-green {
background: green!important;
color: #fff!important;
}
td.highlight-yellow {
background: yellow!important;
color: #000!important;
}
td.highlight-red {
background: red!important;
color: #fff!important;
}
```

and jsfiddle:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tuG6C/1188/)

Answer (score 0):

It works fine if you apply the below change:

```js
$('.highlight-green').tooltip({placement : 'top', container: 'body'});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).